# Making a privacy policy in Swift: How to make UIAlertController action button disabled until message is scrolled to the bottom

Tags: swift, uialertcontroller, uialertaction

In my iOS application I am trying to implement an easy privacy policy using a UIAlertController. By law, the policy has to be scrollable before it can be accepted - like most privacy policies these days.

From my own research I have seen that you can disable and enable UIAlertAction buttons but I don't know how to identify when the UIAlertController message body has been scrolled. Scrolling all the way to the bottom may be a requirement and I am interested in figuring out a way that would work too.

[image: UIAlertController]

Here is my current code for the default looking UIAlertController above.

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Privacy Policy", message: privacyPolicyString, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

let AcceptAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Accept", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {(action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in

    //perform next step in login verification
})

let DeclineAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Decline", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {(action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in

    //User has declined privacy policy. The view resets to standard login state
})

alertController.addAction(AcceptAction)
alertController.addAction(DeclineAction)

self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: you need to make your own alert view for that so you will have access to offset of that view and ability to disable or enable button

Answer (score 1):

This can be possible with native UIAlertController as follows:-

1. Create variable of type `UIAlertAction`
2. Set `enabled` to false
3. When you scrolled to bottom, you can check this on scroll view delegate or any custom way, then set the `enabled` to true
4. The most important thing in below code is:-

   ```
   self.actionToEnable = action
   action.enabled = false
   ```

Code reference:-

```
weak var actionToEnable : UIAlertAction?

func callbackWhenScrollToBottom(sender:UIScrollView) {
    self.actionToEnable?.enabled = true
}

       let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Long text here", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Accept", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: { (_) -> Void in

        })

        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Decline", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (_) -> Void in

        })

        alert.addAction(cancel)
        alert.addAction(action)

        self.actionToEnable = action
        action.enabled = false
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: This is a good start! Can you provide some insight into how I find the scroll offset of the alert in the callback? And where I would call that function?

Comment: I checked the hierarchy of UIAlertController, but not able to find any scrollview, textview. Thus not able to get scroll offset. Have you find any solution.

Comment: No not yet unfortunately. I'm still looking into it!